# Элемент не движется при скролле

Tags: javascript

Почему при скролле вниз песик не двигается(он должен переместится с право  на лево).

Подскажите что я написал неправильно ?

**Код:**

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
    
window.onload = function(){
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  scrolled = (scrolled - 0.001) / 100 | 0;

    var  background = ["512px 445px","500 445px","490px 445px","480px 445px","470px 445px","460px 445px","450px 445px","440px 445px","430px 445px","420px 445px"];

    var coord = scrolled <=1 ? 0 :scrolled >= 2 ? 9 : scrolled;
    cont.style.backgroundPosition = background[coord];
}
```

```css
#container {
  width:1000px;
  height:1500px;
  border:1px solid;

  background-image:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/3f/6a/e63f6ac9864239e7064f48f94ddc68c6.jpg);

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:512px 445px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Cheapskate/9ep5kb14/)

Comment: Чтобы что-то происходило при скролле нужно обрабатывать событие этого самого скролла.

Comment: @br3t как именно обрабатывать?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp . Я так понимаю, что вам нужно ваши действия в onload выполнять при каждом скролле.

Comment: @br3t вы предлагаете div-у дать onscroll? да действия должны выполнятся в onload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужные действия переносите в функцию, которую вызываете при скролле:

```js
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
    
window.onload = relocate;
window.onscroll = relocate;

function relocate(){
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  scrolled = (scrolled - 0.001) / 100 | 0;

    var  background = ["512px 445px","500 445px","490px 445px","480px 445px","470px 445px","460px 445px","450px 445px","440px 445px","430px 445px","420px 445px"];

    var coord = scrolled <=1 ? 0 :scrolled >= 2 ? 9 : scrolled;
    cont.style.backgroundPosition = background[coord];
}
```

```css
#container {
  width:1000px;
  height:1500px;
  border:1px solid;

  background-image:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/3f/6a/e63f6ac9864239e7064f48f94ddc68c6.jpg);

  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:512px 445px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое